# How to return a & to an internal variable in a custom iterator?

Tags: rust

Say I have the following custom iterator:

```rust
struct Pairs<I: Iterator> {
    inner: I,
    cache: Option<(I::Item, I::Item)>,
}

impl<I> Iterator for Pairs<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: Copy,
{
    type Item = (I::Item, I::Item);
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.cache = match self.cache {
            Some((_, n)) => match self.inner.next() {
                Some(v) => Some((n, v)),
                _ => None,
            },
            _ => match (self.inner.next(), self.inner.next()) {
                (Some(m), Some(n)) => Some((m, n)),
                _ => None,
            },
        };
        self.cache
    }
}
```

Instead of returning a copy of `cache` of type `(I::Item, I::Item)`, how can I return a reference to it, with type `&(I::Item, I::Item)`, or `(&I::Item, &I::Item)`, instead?

[Changing the `Item` to be a reference requires a lifetime](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ea781271c26326d3584e9abc06310f44), and because the reference would be unconstrained by nothing else, I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: You cannot. The `Iterator` interface doesn't allow its `Item` to be linked to the lifetime of `self`.